# Javascript, Sum Textfield wont show SUM

Tags: javascript

But I want to sum up two textfields that will automatically show the answer in the "Total" textfield. Tried onkeyup, and onchange. but it wont work. Here are my HTML codes:

```
<input type="text" value="$0.00" size="6" maxlength="6" name="form[family_home]" id="family_home" onfocus="if (this.value == '$0.00') {this.value=''}" class="assets rsform-input-box">
<input type="text" value="$0.00" size="6" maxlength="6" name="form[home_contents]" id="home_contents" onfocus="if (this.value == '$0.00') {this.value=''}" class="assets rsform-input-box">

<input type="text" value="Total" size="20" name="form[Total]" id="Total" onchange="calculateText();" readonly="readonly" class="rsform-input-box">
```

and here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateText(){

var op1=document.getElementById('family_home');
var op2=document.getElementById('home_contents');
var result=document.getElementById('Total');
if(op1.value=="$0.00" || op1.value!=parseFloat(op1.value)) op1.value=0;
if(op2.value=="$0.00" || op2.value!=parseFloat(op2.value)) op2.value=0;
result.value=0;

result.value=parseFloat(result.value);


result.value=parseFloat(result.value)+parseFloat(op1.value)+parseFloat(op2.value);
</script>
```

Comment: You have to bind the handler to the input fields whose values change, not to `#Total`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the onchange event on the inputs that you're modifying: family_home and home_contents

Comment: you mean like this `<input type="text" value="$0.00" size="6" maxlength="6" name="form[family_home]" id="family_home" onfocus="if (this.value == '$0.00') {this.value=''}" onchange="calculateText();" class="assets rsform-input-box">`